# signup with google or facebook

Tags: laravel-5.6

I am new in laravel and I want to login with google and facebook but I have no idea how to use and integrate in laravel 5.6  Please suggest and help for how to sign up with google and facebook.

Answer (score 0):

There's a package called socialite that makes integrating with social services alot easier. You can check the documentation at [Laravel Socialite](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/socialite).

You pull in the socialite package via composer, and then put the different required social site keys and secrets in the `config/services.php` file as required.